# How to find out how many fibre channel port has my Windows Server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003

O/S: Windows Server 2003. I'm not network manager but was asked to find out how many fibre channel ports has that server. Is it the same as Fibre Channel Adapter shown in Device Manager of Windows?[image]

Is there two fibre channel ports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that means you [probably] have two FC adapters installed.  There could be more that don't have drivers installed for them, there could even be less if someone really screwed something up.  Or it could be one of those situations where a single card has 2 ports on it, and both show up as a separate adapter to Windows.

How that translates to the number of FC ports... depends.  [Adapters can have different numbers of ports](http://www.qlogic.com/products/adapters/pages/fibrechanneladapters.aspx).  Do the adapters on your server have 1 or 2 ports each?

I'd recommend taking a physical look, rather than just guessing or assuming, but if you're hellbent on doing the latter, you should ifnd out the model of card in there and look up how many ports it has.

Comment: +1 for look at the back and count.

Comment: @Grant  Wish I could say I "just knew that" and didn't have to learn it the hard way.